# IntelliJ : Different editor color shemes for different languages

Tags: java, vue.js, intellij-idea, colors, editor

How can I use different editor color schemes for different languages in IntelliJ Ultimate 2022.1.1 ?

Example : I want to use the "Eclipse Dark Theme" scheme when I edit Java files, and the "vuesion-theme" scheme when I edit Vue/JavaScript files.

In *"Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme"* if I select Java and select a Scheme, it's changing the Scheme of all others languages too (JavaScript included).

Is there a way to select different schemes for different languages ?

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Please vote and follow the related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185441/Individual-Color-Schemes-per-language